# Multistage build with docker from multiple sources

Tags: django, docker, dockerfile

I have a django project with different applications and I am trying to build a docker image for every single app. However in development I want a docker image to contain the whole project. I was using some multistage before to handle dev dependencies. Is there any way to achieve the following in a different way?

```
FROM python:3.7-stretch AS base
RUN pip install -r /projectdir/requirements.txt

FROM base AS app1
RUN pip install -r /projectdir/app1/requirements.txt

FROM base AS app2
RUN pip install -r /projectdir/app2/requirements.txt

FROM app1, app2 AS dev
RUN pip install -r /projectdir/requirements_dev.txt
```

Comment: I don't think you need a multistage Dockerfile to achieve that. Installing the requirements from every app in a single stage would be enough

Comment: I know that, but than I cannot only build stage app1 from this dockerfile